# Reset stack after pressing TabBar route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently stuck with my project, I have a lot of nested navigators and I can't figure out how to reset one of them before navigating.

Here's my navigators structure : ( the Screen X is the same )

- MainNavigator

  - TabBarNavigator

    - StackNavigator A

      - Screen A -> navigate to Screen X
      - Screen B
    - StackNavigator B

      - Screen C -> navigate to Screen X
      - Screen D
    - StackNavigator C

      - Screen E -> navigate to Screen X
      - Screen F
    - StackNavigator D
  - Other components

So when i'm navigating from Screen A to screen X, i can still navigate to  other navigators ( B, C, D ) because the tabBar is still present and it's good. 
However, if I open screen X in Navigator A, then navigate to a screen of Navigator B, when I come back on Navigator A I would like to land on Screen A and not on Screen X as it does right now ( the Screen X is still on top of Navigator A's stack ).

To resume, my nav actualy does :
   - Navigator A -> Screen A -> Screen X -> Navigator B -> Screen B -> Go Back to Navigator A but lands on Screen X

And i would like it to do :
   - Navigator A -> Screen A -> Screen X -> Navigator B -> Screen B -> Go back to Navigator A and land on Screen A

I tried to set this up in my Screen X navigation option but it does only work on Navigator A :

```
tabBarOnPress: () => {
    navigation.goBack(navigation.state.key)
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated since i've been stuck on this for a while now.

React : 16.0.0

React Native : https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-23.0.0.tar.gz

React navigation : ^1.0.0-beta.19

Currently working on iOS simulator

Comment: Did you ever use redux? If yes, you can integrate with it and take over control of your routes: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux

Comment: I do use redux, however I have a hard time understanding how it can help here since this look like a "classic" navigation issue.

Answer (score 0):

With redux integration you can use the `reset` method of `NavigationActions`:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions

On the `reset` method example you'll find:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile'})
  ]
})

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation nesting of tab is bit complex I also faced something similar to this

```
NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null,
    actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'routeNameToNavigate'})
    ]
});
```

giving `key` value solved my problem and navigated me root from nested. Hope this will solve your problem. Here is issue dicussed

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1949